# Run two applications in the same AWS Cloud9 instance (front-end and API)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ide, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to run `json-server` on port 8082 to serve some mock data to the front-end I'm developing using `create-react-app` (via `yarn start` to get the dev server on port 8080). Although both servers run correctly in their respective terminals, I can only access the first one I run from the AWS-provided URL, thus making it impossible to perform any kind of HTTP request from the React app to the json-server.

How should I go about this? Probably running two EC2 instances would work, but that seems awfully inefficient...

Comment: so are you setting any reverse proxy for your apps? because or if the json-server is exposed are you using `proxy` in your react package.json?

Comment: Basically my question is can the json-server be connected(requested) over the internet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. json-server can be connected to *if* it's the first server I launch. But then I can't access my React app. And if I fire up the react dev server first, then it won't let me `fetch` any content from json-server.
I haven't set up any proxies, and I'd rather not complicate things, if possible. It shouldn't be that hard, right? Every full-stack developer using Cloud9 must be on the same boat, but I couldn't find any previous answer...

Comment: Hey @Dijkie85 were you able to solve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @Tomowa sort of... Gave up on trying and replaced my backend with Google firebase which is pretty easy to setup